# convert config file into dictionary using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, parsing, configparser

```
[section 1]
key1:value1
key2:value2

[section 2]
key1:value1
key2:value2
```

I have tried to parse this config file  into dictionary using python  but i was unable to do

This is my code:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser
filename = '/home/Documents/dictionary parsing/config.cfg'

def read_config_file(filename):
    with open(file=filename, mode='r') as fs:
        return{k.strip(): v.strip() for i in [l for l in fs.readlines() if l.strip() != ''] for k, v in [i.split('=')]}

print('dictionary: ',read_config_file(filename))
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: you should give a look to [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) the documentation is quite clear and cover your use case

Answer (score 3):

This is the way:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# The name of your file
config.read('example.ini')

dictionary = {}
for section in config.sections():
    dictionary[section] = {}
    for option in config.options(section):
        dictionary[section][option] = config.get(section, option)

print(dictionary)
```

The `sections` method return a list of all the sections in your config file, the `options` method returns all of the options for a section.
Using the `get` method of the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) library you can access all the section-option combo you have loaded from you config file and then place them in a dict with the same schema.